# Mapping to a new value changed all to NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Originally, I have dataframe df1 which contains a gender column, with values Female and Male. Since I want to work with a temp dataframe, I first copied it. See the code:

```
df2 = df1
gMap = {'Female': 1, 'Male': 0}
df2['sex']=df2['sex'].map(gMap)
```

2 problems have occurred:

- All values in sex column have changed to NaN
- Even when I run df1.head, I see the values NaN instead of original gender

An a final question is, how to change the column data type along with mapping, for example, in above, to integer.

Comment: Can you please share a sample input and expected output.

Comment: This is a standard pandas question and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for new `DataFrame` is necessary [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid reference to original DataFrame, so changing the df1 will avoid change the df2.

If no match possible problem are trailing whitespaces, so remove them by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df2 = df1.copy()

print (df2['sex'].unique())

gMap = {'Female': 1, 'Male': 0}
df2['sex']=df2['sex'].str.strip().map(gMap)
```

> Will this change the datatype as well?

It depends.

If all unique values in columns are only `Female` or `Male` (keys in dictionary) then is created new integer column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['Male','Female','Male']})

gMap = {'Female': 1, 'Male': 0}
df2['sex']=df2['sex'].map(gMap)

print (df2)
   sex
0    0
1    1
2    0

print (df2.dtypes)
sex    int64
dtype: object
```

If there is more values, get float column, because non matched values return missing values:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['Male','Female','Another Val']})

gMap = {'Female': 1, 'Male': 0}
df2['sex']=df2['sex'].map(gMap)

print (df2)
   sex
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  NaN

print (df2.dtypes)
sex    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to mind the white spaces. Will this change the datatype as well?